# remove nested values from object in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object called `copyAgencies` which contains a class called `Programs`, which contains various information pertaining to a program (name, id, ect...).

I am trying to write a foreach loop to remove all programs that do not a match a certain `id` parameter.
For example, `copyAgencies` could contain 11 different programs; passing in 3 `id`s means that the other 8 programs should be removed from the `copyAgencies` object.

I tried the following code, which fails. Could you help me making it work?

```cs
foreach (int id in chkIds)
{
    //copyAgencies.Select(x => x.Programs.Select(b => b.ProgramId == id));
    copyAgencies.RemoveAll(x => x.Programs.Any(b => b.ProgramId != id)); //removes all agencies
}
```

Comment: What does the code you have produce?

Comment: give us more information about your classes.as far as I understand you want to remove programs from `Programs`not from the agencies

Comment: the code give me one agency, with 11 programs associated with it. I would like to remove the programs that are not equal to the id's i pass in

Comment: Could you give us an example with specific values?

Comment: so Oject Agency would have AgencyName, AgencyId, Address, Programs(which is another object containing, name, id, ect and at this level the removal should occur)

Comment: So you do want to remove from programs not from copyAgencies?

Comment: What is the datatype of `copyAgencies`? What is the datatype of `Programs`?

Comment: True, remove from the programs but leave the copyAgencies object where it lives in play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one agency like you said in your comment, and that's all you care about, try this:

```
copyAgencies[0].Programs.RemoveAll(x => !chkIds.Contains(x.ProgramId));
```

Comment: That is it Racil, in this function there will only be one agency and never any more. Great thinking!!!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to filter out values is to avoid removing the values you're not interesting but filtering the ones you're interested in:

```
var interestingPrograms = Programs.Where(p => chkIds.Contains(p.Id));
```

In order to apply this to your agencies you can simply enumerate agencies and filter out the `Programs` property

```
var chckIds = new List<int>() {1,2,3};
foreach (var a in agencies)
{
    a.Programs = a.Programs.Where(p => chkIds.Contains(p.Id));
}
```